# How to set different color to different objects in one view by Swift?

Tags: swift

everyone.

I made a practice, it show seven circles, one big and six small.
six small circles are inside the big one.

Now, I want to set different color to the six circles.
How can I do?

Thanks

```
import UIKit
```

class CircleInCircle: UIView {

```
@IBInspectable 
var externalScale: CGFloat = 0.9 {
    didSet {
        externalScale = min(max(externalScale, 0), 1)
    }
}

var externalCenter: CGPoint {
    return convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
}

var externalRadius: CGFloat {
    return min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width) / 2 * externalScale
}

@IBInspectable
var color: UIColor = UIColor.redColor() {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

func scale(gestrue: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestrue.state == .Changed {
        externalScale *= gestrue.scale
        gestrue.scale = 1
    }
}

enum internalCircle {
    case one, two, three, four, five, six
}

func internalCircleCondition(whichCircle: internalCircle, rotate: Double) -> UIBezierPath {

    var internalCenter = externalCenter

    let internalRadius = externalRadius / 15

    switch whichCircle {
    case .one:
        internalCenter = CGPoint(x: externalCenter.x - externalRadius / 7 * 1 * cos(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 1 * CGFloat(rotate)), y: (externalCenter.y - externalRadius / 7 * 1 * sin(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 1 * CGFloat(rotate))))
    case .two:
        internalCenter = CGPoint(x: externalCenter.x - externalRadius / 7 * 2 * cos(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 3 * CGFloat(rotate)), y: (externalCenter.y - externalRadius / 7 * 2 * sin(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 3 * CGFloat(rotate))))
    case .three:
        internalCenter = CGPoint(x: externalCenter.x - externalRadius / 7 * 3 * cos(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 5 * CGFloat(rotate)), y: (externalCenter.y - externalRadius / 7 * 3 * sin(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 5 * CGFloat(rotate))))
    case .four:
        internalCenter = CGPoint(x: externalCenter.x - externalRadius / 7 * 4 * cos(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 7 * CGFloat(rotate)), y: (externalCenter.y - externalRadius / 7 * 4 * sin(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 7 * CGFloat(rotate))))
    case .five:
        internalCenter = CGPoint(x: externalCenter.x - externalRadius / 7 * 5 * cos(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 9 * CGFloat(rotate)), y: (externalCenter.y - externalRadius / 7 * 5 * sin(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 9 * CGFloat(rotate))))
    case .six:
        internalCenter = CGPoint(x: externalCenter.x - externalRadius / 7 * 6 * cos(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 11 * CGFloat(rotate)), y: (externalCenter.y - externalRadius / 7 * 6 * sin(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 11 * CGFloat(rotate))))
    }

    let internalCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: internalCenter, radius: internalRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)

    internalCirclePath.lineWidth = 2

    return internalCirclePath
}

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let externalCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: externalCenter, radius: externalRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)

    externalCirclePath.lineWidth = 3

    color.set()

    externalCirclePath.stroke()

    let rotateRatio = ratio?.rotateRatioInCircle(self) ?? 1.0

    internalCircleCondition(.one, rotate: rotateRatio).stroke()
    internalCircleCondition(.two, rotate: rotateRatio).stroke()
    internalCircleCondition(.three, rotate: rotateRatio).stroke()
    internalCircleCondition(.four, rotate: rotateRatio).stroke()
    internalCircleCondition(.five, rotate: rotateRatio).stroke()
    internalCircleCondition(.six, rotate: rotateRatio).stroke()

  }
```

}

[Demo Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7pQ7.png)

Comment: Why not just like you set their position?

Comment: I tried, but it still keep the same color and turn to the other color I set for case one when I click display. But all circles still the same color, what I want is setting different for different circles.

Comment: Where is that code? If the location code works you can omit that for brevity and show the colour code you tried, explaining what it does wrong.

Comment: I modified my code like below, any wrong? :

`switch whichCircle {
        case .one:
            color = UIColor.blueColor()
            internalCenter = CGPoint(x: externalCenter.x - externalRadius / 7 * 1 * cos(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 1 * CGFloat(rotate)), y: (externalCenter.y - externalRadius / 7 * 1 * sin(CGFloat(M_PI) / 6 * 1 * CGFloat(rotate))))`